# How to save binary pdf data into mobile storage or into a file using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting this "The method 'writeAsBytes' was called on null" issue.

```
openInAppPDF(url) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String baseurl = prefs.getString('baseurl');
    Dialogs.showLoadingDialog(context, _loaderKey); //open the dialog
    var urlencode = Uri.encodeFull(baseurl +
        "MobileApi/Candidate/DonwloadCandidateDocument?FileURL=" +
        url);
    var r = await http
        .get(urlencode, headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
    print(r.statusCode);
    print("load");
    print(r.bodyBytes);
    var response = r.bodyBytes;
    Navigator.of(_loaderKey.currentContext, rootNavigator: true)
        .pop(); //close the dialoge
    File f;
    await f.writeAsBytes(response);
}
```

Thanks in advance
Sourov Bhattacharjee

Answer (score 0):

```
    File f;
    await f.writeAsBytes(response);
```

In your code, f is null. So writeAsBytes method could not work. You need to set a fullPath for the file. After that you can use it like below:

```
   File file = File(fullPath);
   await file.writeAsBytes(response);
```

You can read more from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/writeAsBytes.html).

Comment: where i got the fullPath?have to use path_provider flutter package?

Comment: Of course. You can look at this package too: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_viewer_plugin

Comment: facing below issue after given fullpath.FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.onlinefyjc/app_flutter/'